# How can I install Windows 7 on Ubuntu? (Dual-Boot)

Tags: dual-boot

I tried to follow this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot (scroll half way down), but I didn't understand anything from that page.. 
I need something for beginners, please..

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

excuse my english.   if you know about install Windows System Operative. 
it's easy,
1) begin install Windows 7. . 
2) create partitions, for windows 7 and Ubuntu
3) continue to end installation windows 7.
4) install ubuntu, (previously downloaded the .ISO image and burn a DVD.)
5) take the left partition for Ubuntu
6) share you experience,

Comment: I think you need to create the windows partition in ubuntu and create it as a "primary partition" **before you begin the windows installation**. Also, when finished installing windows, you just need to run BootRepair or reinstall grub to get grub back as the windows installation will erase grub.

Comment: Okay, I have now Ubuntu 14.04 I think, I should create partition for Windows 7, then Install windows 7 on the partition - Okay.  But I don't understand what is the grub and bootrepair, how can I do those things? After I Install windows - what now?